# Regex to match numbers in a string

Tags: regex, string, special-characters

I have the following string from which i need to extract numbers and also "-"s.

**51 Will-Ratelle 6 5 11 - 1.5-5 - 1-0 - - - -**

I am using the regex below to extract numbers which works

```
(\+|-)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

But this will give me only 51, 6, 5, 11, 1.5, -5, 1, -0

I want to extract "-"s also.

I tried few alternatives which reads "-" in the name "Will-Ratelle", which i want to skip.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\B-\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX5pD9/1)

**Explanation**:

- `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - matches float values with or without `-` or `+` sign (`\d+` matches 1+ digits, and `(?:\.\d+)?` matches a dot followed with 1+ sigits 1 or 0 times (optionally))
- `|` - or...
- `\B-\B` - a standalone hyphen not standing right after or before a word (`\B` is a non-word boundary).

Comment: That worked!!. Thanks a lot for the answer as well as the details.